# jQGrid datetime server side filter not working with specific date format

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

jQGrid datetime server side filter not working with specific date format

We have used Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGrid in our Asp.Net application, We have also enabled server side filtering setting LoadOnce = false. We have also implemented localization for Date format for that we are using below code

```
JQGridColumn jc = new JQGridColumn();
jc.DataFormatString = "{0:" + UserDateDisplayFormat + "}";

CustomFormatter jcformatter = new CustomFormatter();
jcformatter.FormatFunction = "FormatNullDateCellValue";
jc.Formatter.Add(jcformatter);
```

Where "FormatNullDateCellValue" JavaScript function is converting datetime format for display in grid.

**Now we are facing issue with specific date format "dd-MM-yyyy" when date is lower then 12 (e.g. 10-02-2018).**

For server side in Asp.Net we have jqGrid_DataRequesting method where we got filtered result with 1 record count.

**But from there when code reaches to loadComplete(data) JavaScript method we found record count 1 but not row data.**

This is strange from we have got so far http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=3964 but this is not helping us.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We have already write a logic in C# for DatTime column that if Date value comes from Database then we are converting that value to DateTime.ToShortDateString() which removes time from date and convert date to string, but when we assign that string to DateTime column it converts that string to DateTime value having 12:00:00 AM because DataTable has column type DateTime. (After getting rows from Database we are manually generating DataTabe here)

Comment: On other note why we can't perform this SQL operation because we have concept of Dynamic columns, you can define new column with DataType, That's why we are doing such operation in C# server side.